# Overflow error on the bottom in flutter application

Tags: flutter

i'm having a `A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.4 pixels on the bottom.` error on my profile page. Actually I have a card in which there are chips that can be updated by the user and some user info in it. After the card I have another widget displaying photos. Once the user picks many chips, the card crosses the bottom widget (photos widget).

So basically, once the card gets longer, it crosses the user photos widget causing that error. I couldn't fix this issue, can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              bottomNavigationBar: const MyCustomNavBar(indexPage: 3),
              body: _profile != null && _categories != null
                  ? SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Stack(children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: screenHeight * 0.32,
                              width: screenWidth,
                              // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 182, 236),
                              color: redColor,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.037),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: screenHeight * 0.01,
                                        left: screenWidth * 0.03),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: screenWidth * 0.1,
                                      height: screenHeight * 0.05,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        color:
                                            Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      ),
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                                          size: screenHeight * 0.025,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      const HomePage()));
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Mon Profil',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        fontSize: screenHeight * 0.025,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: screenHeight * 0.01,
                                        right: screenWidth * 0.03),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: screenWidth * 0.1,
                                      height: screenHeight * 0.05,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        color:
                                            Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      ),
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit_outlined,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      EditProfilePage()));
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: screenHeight * 0.17,
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Card(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                      ),
                                      elevation: 0,
                                      shadowColor: Colors.black,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: screenWidth * 0.8,
                                        height: screenHeight * 0.7,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: screenHeight * 0.045,
                                              right: screenWidth * 0.05,
                                              left: screenWidth * 0.05), //20
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: screenHeight * 0.07,
                                              ),
                                              UserStatsWidget(
                                                  points: 0,
                                                  rank: 12,
                                                  reviews: 0),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: screenHeight * 0.01,
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            'Préférences culinaires',
                                                            style: GoogleFonts
                                                                .lato(
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .black87,
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold,
                                                              fontSize:
                                                                  screenHeight *
                                                                      0.018,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          Container(
                                                            height: 18,
                                                            child:
                                                                GestureDetector(
                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                _showEditPopup(
                                                                    context);
                                                              },
                                                              child:
                                                                  CircleAvatar(
                                                                backgroundColor:
                                                                    Colors
                                                                        .transparent,
                                                                child: Icon(
                                                                  Icons
                                                                      .edit_outlined,
                                                                  size: 15,
                                                                  color:
                                                                      redColor,
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: screenHeight * 0.01,
                                                  ),
                                                  _profile != null &&
                                                          _profile!.prefTags !=
                                                              null
                                                      ? Wrap(
                                                          spacing: screenWidth *
                                                              0.015,
                                                          children: _profile!
                                                              .prefTags!
                                                              .map((title) {
                                                            return Chip(
                                                              label: Text(
                                                                title,
                                                                style:
                                                                    GoogleFonts
                                                                        .lato(),
                                                              ),
                                                              backgroundColor:
                                                                  Color
                                                                      .fromARGB(
                                                                          255,
                                                                          255,
                                                                          223,
                                                                          223),
                                                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                  color: Colors
                                                                      .black87),
                                                              shape:
                                                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius
                                                                        .circular(
                                                                            20),
                                                              ),
                                                              side: BorderSide
                                                                  .none,
                                                            );
                                                          }).toList(),
                                                        )
                                                      : Container(
                                                          width:
                                                              screenWidth * 0.3,
                                                          height: screenHeight *
                                                              0.015,
                                                          decoration:
                                                              BoxDecoration(
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .transparent,
                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                BorderRadius
                                                                    .circular(
                                                                        50),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: screenHeight * 0.02,
                                              ),
                                              UserInfosWidget(
                                                email: _profile!.email == "" ||
                                                        _profile!.email == null
                                                    ? "Email non mis à jour"
                                                    : _profile!.email!,
                                                num: (_profile!.tel == null ||
                                                        _profile!.tel == 0)
                                                    ? "Téléphone non mis à jour"
                                                    : _profile!.tel.toString(),
                                                birthDate: _profile!
                                                            .birthDate !=
                                                        null
                                                    ? DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                                                        .format(_profile!
                                                            .birthDate!)
                                                    : "Date de naissance non mise à jour",
                                                address: (_profile!.address ==
                                                            "" ||
                                                        _profile!.address ==
                                                            null)
                                                    ? "Adresse non mis à jour"
                                                    : _profile!.address!,
                                                codePostal:
                                                    (_profile!.zipCode == 0 ||
                                                            _profile!.zipCode ==
                                                                null)
                                                        ? "0000 - "
                                                        : _profile!.zipCode
                                                            .toString(),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                //here
                                Container(
                                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                        maxHeight: screenHeight * 0.78),
                                    color: redColor,
                                    child: UserPhotosWidget(listPhotos: imgs)),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.125),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    CircleAvatar(
                                      child: Image.asset("assets/avatar.png"),
                                      radius: 38,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.015),
                                    Text(_profile!.name)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : LoadingProfilePage())
```